# Вывести строку при помощи regexp

Tags: golang

Я знаю что при помощи метода Match и Compile в regexp можно находить нужные нам строки, числа, знаки и т.д.

Как я знаю значение `Match` может содержатся только `bool`. Но мне нужен только результат вывода, допустим `012345678, 192.168.0.1` тоесть числовые значения. 
*Как мне вывести значение `Match` метода? Код:*

```
ss_match_body := req.Body
check_all_chunk_int, _ := regexp.Compile("[0-9]+")
if check_all_chunk_int.Match(ss_match_body) {
    fmt.Println("IP is found!", check_all_chunk_int.Match)
    for i := 0; i < 11; i++ {
        go FCAAHTTP(os.Args[1], 80)
    }

} else {
    fmt.Println("IP not found... exit) 
}
```

Edit переделал код как сказал Ainar-G:

```
func main() {

    url := os.Args[1]
    for {
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 1) /* check every 20 seconds */
        req, err := http.Get(url) /* HTTP Get method into global server*/
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("[Info] [HTTP.Method.Connection.Fatal] HTTP connection negative... 404") /* Check server response for nil value*/


        } else {

            defer req.Body.Close()
            simple_match_body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(req.Body)

            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("[Info] [Fatal] Error read body")
                continue

            } else {
                check_assign_word := regexp.MustCompile("/check/")
                match_result := check_assign_word.FindAll(simple_match_body, -1)
                for _, bc := range match_result {

                    // fmt.Println("[Info] [HTTP.Method] (.http-target) (exp) check word not found!... done", req.Body)

                    /* for i := 0; i < 1124; i++ {
                        go FierceHTTPAttack(os.Args[1], 80)
                    } */
                    fmt.Printf(">>%s<<\n", bc)
                }


                if len(match_result) == 0 {
                    fmt.Println("[Info] [HTTP.Method.NOTFOUND] (.http-target chect) {exp} check word not found...")
                }



                check_source_ip_target := regexp.MustCompile("[0-9]+")
                match_result_a := check_source_ip_target.FindAll(simple_match_body, -1) 
                for _, bcc := range match_result_a {

                    /* for i := 0; i < 1124; i++ {
                        go FierceHTTP(os.Args[1], 80)
                    } */
                    fmt.Printf(">>%s<<\n", bcc)

                } 

                if len(match_result_a) == 0 {
                    fmt.Println("[Info] [Target.IP.Error] (.http-word) (exp) word IP not found... retry", check_source_ip_target)
                } else {
                    fmt.Println("[Info] [TT.IP] (.http-word) (exp) source IP is found!... done ", req.Body)
                }


                }


            }

        }




}
```

Вывод:

```
>>3<<
>>4<<
>>01<<
>>3<<
>>4<<
>>8<<
>>192<<
>>168<<
>>0<<
>>1<<
>>9999999<<
>>0<<
>>100<<
>>0<<
>>000<<
>>000<<
>>000<<
>>000<<
>>23024110<<
>>20663010<<
>>9968<<
>>22<<
>>55<<
>>11<<
>>6<<
>>941<<
>>894<<
>>2<<
>>78<<
>>000<<
```

На моей html странице присутствует только одна строка с числами: 192.168.0.1 больше там не в исходном коде, не где, нечего нету. Но мне выводит данную белиберду. Мне нужно все вывести одной строкой, а не с переносом строки. Или можно просто считывать определенную строку, это тоже мне не ясно. Хоть документацию IO читал

HTML Source Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>nothings/</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  check 192.168.0.1
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавив регулярное выражение для **IPv4** адреса: `(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\‌​d\d?)` у меня вывелся нужный мне результат.

Answer (score 1):

В таком случае вам надо использовать методы `Find*`. Например:

```
data := []byte(`123 abc 456`)
r := regexp.MustCompile(`[[:digit:]]+`)
matches := r.FindAll(data, -1)
for _, b := range matches {
    fmt.Printf(">>%s<<\n", b)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/xqdUyS1uEx.

Docs: https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.FindAll.

Соответственно, если `len(matches) == 0`, то не найдено ни одного совпадения.

Comment: У меня ошибка при MustCompile пишет что нужно 2 аргумента. Я изменил на обычный Compile, у меня просто идут 1 за другим цифры 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 и так до 29. Строку которую нашло не выводит: >>%!s(int=0)<<
>>%!s(int=0)<<
>>%!s(int=1)<<
>>%!s(int=2)<<
>>%!s(int=3)<<
>>%!s(int=4)<<
>>%!s(int=5)<<
>>%!s(int=6)<<
>>%!s(int=7)<<
>>%!s(int=8)<<
>>%!s(int=9)<<
>>%!s(int=10)<<
>>%!s(int=11)<<
>>%!s(int=12)<<

Comment: @JackSmith Уважайте тех, кто вам отвечает. Добавьте код в вопрос и не заставляйте людей проявлять экстрасенсорные способности. MustCompile принимает один аргумент, FindAll - два. Кроме того, вы скорее всего перепутали индекс итерации со значением.

Comment: обновил информацию как вы просили

Comment: @JackSmith Как я и говорил, вы спутали индекс и значение. Вместо `for bc := range match_resul` пишите `for _, bc := range match_result`. И вообще, почитайте [*хоть что-нибудь*](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html) про го.

Comment: да, я перепутал индексы. Я прочитал статьи "основы golang" так же документации на офф сайте, но не все, чуть более половины. Потому что я не успел, я учу Golang 4 дня и чтоб понять все это мне нужно больше времени.Поэтому я и обратился на stackoverflow. Можете помочь в последнем вопросе, почему у меня некорректно отображаются числа.

Comment: @JackSmith Опять заставляете людей гадать, не даёте HTML-кода страницы. Откуда нам знать, что у вас там нету других цифр? Если вам нужен именно IP-адрес, то регулярка для него другая.

Comment: добавил в вопрос

Comment: @JackSmith Как я и говорил, цифры есть. Делайте регулярку для айпишника. Извините, но сегодня я вам больше помогать не буду.

Comment: умный же вы человек! Сработало по такой регулярке: ((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)